# Repeating action specific number of times if condition is not met

Tags: c#, for-loop, console

i am trying to make a console app with password access,managed to write the code to ask for the password ,but i want it to repeat asking for the password(if it is wrong) 4 times only not forever , i tried to do it with for loop but it didn't work ,can somebody tell me where is the problem ?

```
 class Password
    {
        public static bool verifyPassword()
        {
            bool loginSuccess1;
            Console.WriteLine("enter password");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            string password = "12";
            loginSuccess1 = (userInput == password);
            return loginSuccess1;

        }
        public static void checkPassword()
        {
            bool loginSuccess;
            int loginCount = 1;
            loginSuccess = verifyPassword();
            while (!loginSuccess && loginCount < 5)
            {

                verifyPassword();
                if (!loginSuccess)
                    loginCount++;
            }
            if (loginSuccess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("correct answer");
            }

        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Password.checkPassword();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the password is incorrect, it calls `wrongPassword`. That then calls `verifyPassword` 4 times (as you suspected), except if you get it *wrong* again, it calls `wrongPassword` again, which calls `verifyPassword` four times again... you get the idea.

I would have `verifyPassword` return a bool (if it succeeded), and not call `wrongPassword` (just eliminate that function) and then have just one new function:

```
bool loginSuccess;
int loginCount = 1;

while (!loginSuccess && loginCount < 5)
{
    loginSuccess = VerifyPassword();

    if (!loginSuccess)
        loginCount++;
}
```

Now you don't have a recursive loop, and it will only check 4 times.

Comment: not working with me, if you answered wrong at the 1st time then answered right it won`t break the loop , i made a simplified version of the code ,here it is,try it for your self

Comment: @AmgadElsaiegh In your version, you don't reassign `loginSuccess` in the loop. Make sure you do that. It works for me when I use the actual code I posted.